# /Home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I want to resize the home partition to have only 500gb, so then i can make a dual boot setup.

[HD /home partition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2KcR.png)

[SSD linuxSO partition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83HFN.png)

Comment: You need to do it from a live session.

Comment: Hello, please check the images that you posted above, they both show the same thing, i.e. the HD.

Comment: thx for remind me. now is right

Comment: The only new partitions you can create on your SDD are logical partitions within the 20GB extended partition.  You already have four primary partitions, so the 132GB unallocated is not usable.  Maybe delete the extended, expand the linux, and make the 132GB extended for additional logical partitions.  As for /home, just unmount it, shrink it, and remount it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it no problem but as correctly stated above, you must boot into a live session to do it. GParted can't do it while the partition is mounted.

GParted is pretty straightforward to use, but if you need further guidance, don't hesitate to ask.

The procedure is different to installing Ubuntu with Windows already installed.

If you want to install Windows 10 in Ubuntu, **make sure that the intended partition for the Windows OS is the Primary NTFS partition**. You need to create this on Ubuntu, specifically for Windows installation purposes.

To create the partition, use the GParted or Disk Utility command-line tools. If you already have a logical/extended partition, you’ll need to delete it and create a new Primary Partition. Keep in mind that all data in the existing partition will be erased.

**Installing Windows 10**
Use the bootable DVD/USB stick to start the Windows installation process. First, you’ll need to provide the Windows Activation Key to authenticate your installation. After this, choose Custom Installation, because the automatic option may create issues.

Make sure that you select the NTFS Primary Partition that you’ve created earlier as your Windows 10 installation partition. Keep in mind that after the successful Windows 10 installation, GRUB will be replaced by the Windows bootloader, meaning that you won’t see the GRUB menu when booting your computer. Fortunately, this is easy to solve by installing GRUB for Ubuntu again.

**Installing GRUB for Ubuntu**
In order to install and fix GRUB, a LiveCD or LiveUSB of Ubuntu is a must. This means that you’re going to have to get an independent version of Ubuntu. Having a pen drive is ideal here, as you can use it easily.

Once Live Ubuntu has been loaded, open the Terminal and use the following commands to start boot-repair to fix GRUB for Ubuntu:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

After the installation is done, boot-repair will launch automatically. Select the recommended repair option when repairing the GRUB. Once everything is done, reboot your computer and you’ll see the GRUB menu, where you choose which OS you want to run.

The above information was obtained from [this website](https://www.alphr.com/install-windows-10-alongside-ubuntu/).

Comment: so if i want to resize the HD to 500gb i need to enter the linux intalation menu?

Comment: @ViniciusScarabelli No. You need to make a bootable USB drive or CD the same way you installed Ubuntu on your machine. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview .

Comment: okay, just  a question, because i dont know if i want dual boot still. but my SSD has 180gb free. if I resize the linux partition and my /home is still in the HDD won't be a lot of space for linux?